# Read audio output playing in the background by other app

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, core-audio, avaudiosession

I have been trying to read the audio frequency amplitude levels of a music track playing in the background (by a music streaming/playing app) so I can make a visualizer for it.

So far I can get the current playing iPodMusic background track, but in order to analyse it, I need to cut off the external music and play it in-app so I can analyse it.

**What I really need is access to the audio output frequency/amplitude levels. How can I read the audio output in my app so I can analyse ANY other apps music playing at that moment?**

*This is what I got so far with the iPodMusicPlayer app:*

```
- (void)playPause
{
    __autoreleasing NSError* error;
    _audioPlayer = [_audioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:[[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] error:&error];
    _audioPlayer.currentTime = [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] currentPlaybackTime];
    _audioPlayer.volume = 1;
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [_audioPlayer play];
    [_audioPlayer setMeteringEnabled:YES];
    [_audioPlayer updateMeters];

    if (_isPlaying)
    {
        // Pause audio here
        [_audioPlayer pause];

        [_toolBar setItems:_playItems];  // toggle play/pause button
    }
    else
    {
        // Play audio here
        [_audioPlayer play];

        [_toolBar setItems:_pauseItems]; // toggle play/pause button
    }
    _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;

    if (!_isUpdating)
    {
        _isUpdating = TRUE;
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateUILables) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}


-(void)updateUILables
{
    NSMutableArray* amps = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < _audioPlayer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
        [amps addObject:@(([_audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:i] + 160.0) / 160.0)];
        if (i == 0)
            self.channel0Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f0.6", [_audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:i]];
        else if (i == 1)
            self.channel1Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f0.6", [_audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:i]];

        NSLog(@"Amplitude: %f db for channel %i", [_audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:i], i);
    }
    float amp = 0;
    for (NSNumber *x in amps) {
        amp += [x floatValue];
    }
    amp /= amps.count;
    NSLog(@"amp: %f", amp);

    self.cumulativeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f0.6", amp];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Inter-App Audio", which supports doing something similar. Apple has some examples here, and I believe you can dig up some past WWDC talks on it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/InterAppAudioSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

As iOS apps are sandboxed, direct access to other app's audio will be restricted unless there's an official API for it (which I might have missed). As a workaround you can try to enable microphone input and pickup the audio playing in the background; although I am not sure if or how well it would work. You'd have to experiment with the AudioSession categories to make sure the audio is mixable if going down that route.